# What mesh to buy (and where to buy it) for gabion walls?

Tags: concrete, masonry, stone, retaining-wall, ground

I'd like to build a DIY gabion wall. I've watched many tutorials, but I'm at a loss on where to buy the mesh the build the baskets from. I saw the mesh at the local Home Depot store and it was rusted, unsightly, and dented. I'm hoping for a clean straight look. I also looked in the local stone supply and found nothing. I'm in the Philadelphia, PA area.

So my questions are

1. What kind of mesh won't rust? What keyword am I looking for? (Galvanized?)
2. What kind of store can I buy it at?

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic, which this mostly is....

Comment: Changed from "where can I buy it?" to "What kind of store can I buy it at?". I don't mean to ask a shopping question. I just don't know what the primary use for those meshes is.

Comment: Try searching for [galvanized fencing](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Lumber-Composites-Fencing-Welded-Wire-Fencing/N-5yc1vZc3lp) rather than the concrete reinforcement mesh you've probably seen.

Comment: There are galvanized baskets and polymer-coated galvanized baskets. https://www.maccaferri.com/us/products/gabions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done further research following brhan's suggestion and I have found a galvanized fencing that's 12 gauge. [Here](https://www.deerbusters.com/metal-deer-fence/welded-wire-fence/8-x-100-12-ga-pvc-coated-galvanized-welded-wire-2-x-4/) is a link to product. It comes in various sizes, including 8' wide.

Pivoting this discussion, what I'm wondering about is whether 12 gauge would offer sufficient strength in a retaining wall application?

Comment: SE isn't a discussion forum, and therefore there are no pivots. Please post a new question if you have one, and accept this answer to close this question.